# How to get sheet information in qlik app using nodejs

Tags: node.js, qliksense

Created an app in qlik and created the sheet then uploaded the data for that.
Using uploaded data we created the reports like bar chart pie chart etc.
Once we save how we come to know about the reports are saved in sheet level.

We are trying with qrs/app/id api for getting the modified date but we are not able to get the sheet information in that app.

Answer (score 0):

Sheets and objects (and a lot other stuff) are part of the qvf file. So if the file/app is saved then this means that all app contents are also saved.

The Repository (QRS) API will not provide you with much info about the app content. If you want info about the app content you should "ask" the [Engine](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/June2019/Subsystems/EngineAPI/Content/Sense_EngineAPI/introducing-engine-API.htm).

The communication with the Engine is done via `websocket` and there is `JavaScript` library that can be used - [Enigma](https://github.com/qlik-oss/enigma.js)

You can use the `Engine API Explorer` from the `Dev Hub` to communicate with the Engine

- navigate to `http://my-qs-server/dev-hub`
- choose `Engine API Explorer`#
- press `Connect to engine` button (and wait while communication is established. Should be fast)
- At this point the app list should be populated
- choose an app from the drop down
- Use the table below to send API requests and observe the responses at the bottom